# [python]Help Treating data

Tags: python, ldap

Im new in progamming and i struggling to treat some datas.

I made this code:

```py
import ldap, sys
import json

l = ldap.initialize("ldap://xxx.xxx.x.xx")
username = "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=capam,DC=server" 
password = "xxxxxxxx"
teste = "teste2"
basedn = "DC=capam,DC=server"
searchFilter = "(&(description=%s)(!(uid=user321)))" %teste
searchAttribute = ["uid","description"]

try:

    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.simple_bind_s(username, password) 
    print("conectou.")

except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:

    print ("Your username or password is incorrect.")
    sys.exit(0)

try:

    result_id = l.search(basedn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, searchFilter, searchAttribute)

    result_set = []
    while 1:
        result_type, result_data = l.result(result_id, 0)
    
        if (result_data == []):
            break
        else:
            ## if you are expecting multiple results you can append them
            ## otherwise you can just wait until the initial result and break out
            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:                
                result_set.append(result_data)
                #print(result_data)

    print(result_set[0])
    print(result_set[1])
    
except ldap.LDAPError:
    print("erro.")

sys.exit(0)
```

Output:

```
[('CN=users02,OU=teste,DC=capam,DC=server', {'description': [b'teste2'], 'uid': [b'Users02test']})]

[('CN=user3,CN=Users,DC=capam,DC=server', {'description': [b'teste2'], 'uid': [b'userTest']})]
```

Now i need understand what is this 'b' before the data collected and how do i get only the description value or uid value.Can someone teach how to do?
Further i will create a csv file with this data's.

Answer (score 0):

The 'b' indicates that what's returned is an instance of the class `bytes`.

```py
result_set = [
    [('CN=users02,OU=teste,DC=capam,DC=server', {'description': [b'teste2'], 'uid': [b'Users02test']})],
    [('CN=user3,CN=Users,DC=capam,DC=server', {'description': [b'teste2'], 'uid': [b'userTest']})],
    ]

for data in result_set:
    for (_, d) in data:
        print(d['description'][0].decode('utf8'), d['uid'][0].decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Tank you very much.